# Where can I report a bug relating to Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

I think I have some bugs to report when I use it but I wonder where to report those bugs. Where should I report a Google Plus bug?

Comment: In addition to using the feedback tool it would be good to vote for known issues at http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs or http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update (19/09/2012):**

This procedure has changed. To send feedback regarding Google+ follow the steps below:

1. Click on the cog wheel button in the upper-right part of the page
2. Click on **Send feedback**
   [image]
3. Follow the steps in the window that will appear

[Source](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/learnmore.html).

---

1. Go to you Google+ account.
2. In the bottom right corner you have a **Send Feedback** button.[image]
3. Click it
4. A form will open allowing you to submit a bug. [image]

> To report an issue, go to Google+ and click “Send feedback” at the bottom of the page.

From here: http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/

Answer (score 4):

From [Google+ Discuss](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/):

> To report an issue, [go to Google+](https://plus.google.com/) and click “Send feedback” at
>   the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Google+ Help Forum](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/) if you want to report an issue you need to use the "Send Feedback" at the bottom of the page.

> Find answers to your Google+ questions, and build karma by sharing
>   your knowledge in our Google+ Discuss community. **To report an issue,
>   [go to Google+](https://plus.google.com/) and click “Send feedback” at the bottom of the
>   page.** [Check out our posting guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/answer.py?answer=1353030&hl=en) before you post. And
>   remember, the fastest way to seek help is by [searching our help
>   center](http://www.google.com/support/+/). Non-English user? You can [post in our International
>   category](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/categories/google-plus-discuss/international) in your own language.