# Where should I report a bug relating to Google +1 button?

Tags: google-plus-1

This is not Google+ directly, so I'm not sure if the [answer for Google+](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/where-can-i-report-a-bug-relating-to-google-plus) is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've had a great time working with you all in the Webmaster Central forum, but it's time for a small change. As the Google+ platform grows and the +1 button social plugin becomes a more integral part of that Google+ platform, we'll be moving the primary support channel for questions about the +1 button on your site to the general Google+ platform forum.

From [Webmaster Central](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/google-1-button/vpJPZfxNk7Q) on Google Product Forums, filtered for “Google +1 button” category.

So in my opinion, you can either use these forums or the *Send feedback* form from Google+ pages.